# Silverlight dropdown menu in a html page?

Tags: silverlight

I'm not too familiar with silverlight, so I'm pretty sure I am asking a basic question.

**Is it possible to have a silverlight dropdown menu (like superfish, or so-called dhtml menus) in a web page that will ;**

1. not use more space in the page than
   the first level
2. will go over html content when we
   expand it.

I guess that Silverlight has to be displayed inside a certain "canvas" like flash, so the silverlight menu has to be either :

- as big as the fully expanded menu can
  be -- with the possibility to display
  html over it (using css?) and make
  sure that the expanded items goes on
  top of html ==> That seems not really
  easy!
- as small as the first level of menu
  items -- means that silverlight has
  to get out of the canvas to display
  menu items ==> Is that even possible?

I know that this may sound ridiculous, but the project is to modernize the portal around sql server reporting services using silverlight in a sharepoint webpart. There's no possibility to change the setup, I just want to know if that could be achieved using silverlight. If it can't, we will fall back to superfish.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Silverlight plugin should be set to windowless, so its content can overlap with html. Because Silverlight can not draw outside of its own surface you would have to make as large as biggest menu element or you could resize Silverlight container dynamically through javascript bridge.